# Matrix V for Guttman transform in R

Tags: r, multi-dimensional-scaling

I'm trying to write a code to get matrix V. V is given as [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDM43.png). Wij is `matrix(1,n,n)`
This it what I have so far but it gives me a matrix of only 1's and 11's. It think this is not right. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
V <- function(X) {
  row_V <- nrow(X)
  value_v <- matrix(0, nrow = row_V, ncol = row_V)
  i <- 1
  j <- 1
  X_matrix <- as.matrix(dist(X))
  for (i in 1:nrow(value_v)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(value_v)) {
      if (X_matrix[1,j] == 0) {
        value_v[i, j] <- 0
      }
      else {
        value_v[i, j] <- -1
      }
    }
  }
  for (i in 1: nrow(waarde_v)) {
    if (value_v[i] == value_v[i])
      value_v[i, i] <- -1 * sum(value_v[i,])
  }
  return(value_v)
}
```

I'm using this data set matrix:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
1   0  6  9 17 16 18 32 19 27   7  24  30
2   6  0 14 21 22 29 31 15 26  10  27  36
3   9 14  0  8 15 11 30 20 25  13  27  22
4  17 21  8  0 18  6 29 24 29  21  32  18
5  16 22 15 18  0 23 44 34 40  13  15  20
6  18 29 11  6 23  0 22 19 18  23  37  22
7  32 31 30 29 44 22  0 16  5  38  55  44
8  19 15 20 24 34 19 16  0 13  25  42  41
9  27 26 25 29 40 18  5 13  0  33  50  41
10  7 10 13 21 13 23 38 25 33   0  17  30
11 24 27 27 32 15 37 55 42 50  17   0  33
12 30 36 22 18 20 22 44 41 41  30  33   0
```

Comment: What is `luyken`?  Where is is supposed to come from?

Comment: luyken is the data set matrix, sorry!

Comment: But how is it getting into the function? Should that be x?

Comment: X should be the luyken matrix

Comment: Well then you need to change that inside the function to say x.  That's certainly part of the problem.